# How are hooks internally implemented?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Lately i have been reading about hooks and was curious to know how they are internally implemented.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function CounterUsingHooks() {
  const [count, setCounter] = useState(5);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(count + 1)}>
        {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I understand that UseState accepts initial value and  returns a pair which upon array destruction gets set as  count and setCounter, where count is set to the first value returned by useState, and setCounter is the second.

I'm just interested in binding the function to the variable part.

why is it required to assign to UseState ? taking above example i can just write as below :

```
var count;
var setCounter=function(count){

count= count+1;
}
```

Could someone please explain me how exactly is UseState implemented ?

Comment: Please refer: https://medium.com/the-guild/under-the-hood-of-reacts-hooks-system-eb59638c9dba

Comment: read more about how React update dom element.  It is using virtual dom internally to compare 2 different states when you are calling this setCounter function and then it will change actual dom accordingly.

Comment: React source code: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L83-L88 Also, read up on [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), it's how react's state & lifecycle management works. Docs are a wonderful source of information, if written half-way decently.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand the Fundamentals of [State](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in React.

State is a JavaScript object that stores a component’s dynamic data and determines the component’s behaviour. Because state is dynamic, it enables a component to keep track of changing information in between renders and for it to be dynamic and interactive.